# How we get the element of flyOut menu for WebEx share screen window?

Tags: pywinauto

Steps:
1.Open webEx meeting
2.Click Share-->share my screen

**Environment Python version:** 3.7.2
**pywinauto:** 0.6.8
 
**Operating system:** Windows 10

```
def test_webex_productive_tool():

    app = Application(backend='uia').start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools\ptoneclk.exe")
    mainWebExWindow = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title = "WebEx Productivity Tools")
    cisoWebExMeetingWin = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title = "Cisco Webex Meetings")   
    cisoWebExMeetingWin.ShareMenuItem.click_input() # click share from main menu 
    #cisoWebExMeetingWin.MyScreenMenuItem.click_input()  #Click My Screen share from share--->Menu
    keyboard.press("S")
    keyboard.release("S")
    pywinauto.mouse.move(coords=(377, 25))
    #print(cisoWebExMeetingWin.Youresharingyourscreen.texts()[0])
    #elements = pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements(class_name="wcl_manager1", control_type="Button")
    elements = pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements(class_name="wcl_manager1", control_type="Pane")
    print(elements)
```

Also tried with different ways using options using parent, class and name but every time it returns null

[**Please find the Attached for reference:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttbvE.jpg)

[First screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttbvE.jpg) 
[2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkyYB.jpg)

Comment: Why you're trying to use low level function `find_elements`? It's not recommended to use. You can do everything using `app` and `cisoWebExMeetingWin` objects. Read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for more details.

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov, I have tried with both cisoWebExMeetingWin & app objects but every time it throws **ElementNotFoundError**.                                              **Below stack trace:**         cisoWebExMeetingWin.Stopsharingyourscreenandreturntoyourmeetingwindow.texts()                                                
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError

Comment: Let's check which top level windows are available by calling `cisoWebExMeetingWin.windows()` or `app.windows()`. Maybe you need 1st level top window and then 2nd level button to search on this window.